# In python, Beautiful Soup module parsing problem

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to make something that collect the words which I want from the site.
But As the pictures, I can see the words when I "Inspect" the website. But, I cannot see the words, which I saw on Inspect, in the sources of the website. Therefore, I cannot take them with request and soup modules. How can I get these words? Do you know any way?

Thank You

[image: Inspect]

[image: Sources]

my codes;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import lxml

url = "https://www.m5bilisim.com/tr/on-parmak/hiz-testi/"
reqest = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqest,"lxml")
result = soup.find_all("span")
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website is loaded via `JavaScript`, so `requests` will not help you to render the `JS` as you can confirm that by viewing page source instead of inspect the element. or Just disable `JavaScript` within your browser and check if the elements presented.

Here, i find the `XHR` request which obtain the elements and made a `POST` call to it.

```py
import requests


def main(url):
    r = requests.post(url).json()
    print(r)


main("https://www.m5bilisim.com/tr/on-parmak/hiz-testi/_vt/tr/1.json")
```

Output:

```
bir ve olmak bu için o ben demek çok yapmak ne gibi daha almak var kendi gelmek ile vermek ama sonra kadar yer en insan değil her istemek yıl çıkmak görmek gün biz gitmek iş şey ara ki bilmek el zaman ya çocuk iki bakmak çalışmak içinde büyük yok başlamak yol kalmak neden siz konu yapılmak iyi kadın ev ise diye bulunmak söylemek göz gerekmek 
dünya baş durum yan geçmek sen onlar yeni önce başka hal orta su girmek ülke yemek hiç bile nasıl bütün karşı bulmak böyle yaşamak düşünmek aynı iç ancak kişi bunlar veya ilk göre ön son biri şekil önemli yüz hem göstermek etmek alt getirmek kullanmak çünkü 
taraf şimdi adam onun diğer artık üzerinde ses hep doğru durmak kız tüm çekmek konuşmak para anlamak anne az bazı baba hayat sadece küçük fazla bilgi an sormak bunun öyle yine sağlamak sonuç kullanılmak dış ad yani süre dönmek açmak oturmak anlatmak bırakmak hemen saat yaş sorun devlet sahip sıra yazmak yüzde ay atmak tutmak bunu olay düşmek 
duymak söz güzel sevmek biraz zor çıkarmak şu koymak tek sistem birlikte verilmek kim 
alınmak genç kapı kitap üzerine burada gece alan birbiri işte beklemek uzun hiçbir bugün dönem arkadaş ürün
```